# QGIS python console "Could not create output"

Tags: pyqgis, raster-calculator, qgis-python-console

I'm new to the python console in QGIS and am trying to automate some raster calculations. Below is the code I'm using. I've already changed the path to forward slashes, but when running the script it still gives this error:

> Could not create output D:/folder_main/subfolder/test.tif

How can I solve this?

```py
lyr = QgsRasterLayer('D:/folder_main/subfolder/ortho.tif')

entries = []
# red layer
ras = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
ras.ref = 'ras@1'
ras.raster = lyr
ras.bandNumber = 1
entries.append(ras)
# green layer
ras = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
ras.ref = 'ras@2'
ras.raster = lyr
ras.bandNumber = 2
entries.append(ras)
# blue layer
ras = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
ras.ref = 'ras@3'
ras.raster = lyr
ras.bandNumber = 3
entries.append(ras)

output = 'D:/folder_main/subfolder/test.tif'
calc = QgsRasterCalculator('ras@1 *2', output, 'GTiff', lyr.extent(), lyr.width(), lyr.height(), entries)
calc.processCalculation()
print(calc.lastError())
```

Comment: Does the path `D:/folder_main/subfolder` exist?